# 不管是谁对你们动的手: I've been quite lost towards that end "动的手". Could anyone explain that for me?

Tags: meaning-in-context

My problem is pretty much what's written in the title.
不管是谁对你们动的手 is the question. I've been quite lost towards that end "动的手". Could anyone explain that for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

动手 is a compound word made up of 动 (move/ start) and 手 (hand). Together as a single word, it means 'take action', and the most common extended meaning is 'start to attack'

Since 动 and 手 in 动手 can be broken down to [v] +[n], you can add possess marker 的 before the noun 手 to reclaim the noun status of 手. And a subject (in this case, 谁) before the verb 动 would possess the noun

Example

动手 - start to attack

谁动手 - who started to attack (v)

谁动的**手** - the **attack**(n) that started(v) by whoever(n)

手 has become a noun for 'attack' in this instance

Similar example:

[唱(v): sing + 歌(n): song] = [唱歌(v): to sing]

我唱歌 = 我(n) + 唱歌(v)

我唱的**歌** = the **song** that I sing

*歌 in 唱歌 reclaims its noun status and means 'song'*

More examples:

開車(v): to drive --> 他**開**的**車** (車 is a noun here for 'car') - the **car** he **drives**

做飯(v): to cook --> 姊姊**做**的**飯** (飯 is a noun here for 'meal') - the **meal** my sister **cooked**

Comment: Thank you so much it was extremely helpful! I would never wonder the 的 was separating that word! Really Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

This dictionary definition addressed the use of 的：

> 用在某些句子的动词和宾语之间，强调动作的施事者、受事者或时间、地点、方式等

> E.g. 主任签的字 / 回来坐的飞机/ 他昨天夜里犯的病 / 我在上海念的中学。

Basically, the use of 的 is for ***emphasis***.  In your case, 不管是谁对你们动的手, it emphasizes ***who***(施动者).